# Can an Umpire call "Play" with only one batsman in the ground?

Tags: cricket, officiating

1. Can an Umpire call "Play" with only one batsman in the ground?
2. I follow up the above question with another one....A wicket falls in the last ball of the over just before the call of Time for drinks in an ODI game. Drinks are being brought on to the field. A new batsman also walks in and by the time he reaches his partner, say near the 30 yard circle closer to the pavilion, the captain of the batting side, who is the not-out batsman on the field, sends the new batsman back and asks him to send another batsman in. By the time, the other batsman arrives, the Umpires and the fielders are ready to resume the game. There is only one batsman on the field. 
   Can the Umpire call "Play" now as time for drinks has elapsed? 
   If not, how long should the Umpire wait before he can answer an appeal for Timed out?
   What action should the umpire(s) take?

Note: Play has not been called, hence technically there can be no appeal.

Answer (score 2):

In both of these cases, the umpire should not call "Play".  If the delay is extensive and intentional, the umpires can, after a suitable investigation, consider the batting side to be refusing to play award the match to the fielding side.